# Using Hibernate with Presto

Tags: hibernate, presto

We're currently using Hibernate with Oracle databases which is nice for developers who do not want to deal with SQL statements.

Now there's Facebook's "Presto" and we are asking us if using Hibernate in connection with Presto may be a good idea - or even possible. Or if there is another solution to work around big data without having to develop everything from ground up again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the long run, Presto will work well with tools like Hibernate, but right now, the JDBC driver for Presto is alpha quality.  Improving the JDBC driver is a high priority at Facebook because we need it for an internal project.

Comment: Have there been any updates on this in the last 5 years?  Can Hibernate perform its querying functions via Presto?

Comment: The JDBC driver is pretty complete, and works with most applications now. So, I would expect it will work with Hibernate, but I don't know of anyone that uses Hibernate with Presto.

Comment: I am very interested in knowing if Presto works with EclipseLink.

Comment: @SyCode This answer is 6 years old.  The [Presto JDBC driver](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html) works with all of the major BI tools (e.g., Tableau), so I would expect it to work with Hibernate and EclipseLink. I suggest you try it out and if you run into a problem with the driver, file an issue on the [Presto Github](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues).

Comment: @DainSundstrom thanks for the update, I will try out Presto !